# Approximations of hitting times of biased random walks

Tags: probability

Let $X, X_i$ be iid with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and $h>0$ be the stopping position. Let $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$ and $T$ be the number of steps it takes to walk beyond h. I need to find the distribution of $T$ in terms of the first two moments of $X$, at least approximately, since in my scenario $$h\gg\sigma\gg\mu.$$ We may assume $X_i$ is well behaved, i.e. having finite moments whenever you want. We have $T\leq n$ iff $max(S_1,...,S_n)\geq h$, but I did not find enough fact about the random variable $max(S_1,...,S_n)$. I only know $S_n$ by central limit theorem. If it is asking too much to find the distribution, I also conjecture that the variance of $T$ can be estimated, perhaps in the similar manner of proving $E(S_T)=E(T)E(X)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a standard Brownian motion $B$ and the Brownian motion with drift $Y$ defined by $$Y_t=\sigma B_t+\mu t.$$ Then, when $h$ is large when compared to $\sigma$ and $\mu$, $T$ can be approximated by $$\tau=\inf\{t\gt0\mid Y_t=h\}.
$$
The distribution of $\tau$ is characterized by its Laplace transform, such that, for every nonnegative $u$, $$E(\mathrm e^{-s\tau})=\exp\left(-\frac{h\mu}{\sigma^2}\left(\sqrt{1+2s\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^2}}-1\right)\right).$$
Thus, the renormalized hitting time $$\theta=\frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2}\tau,$$ is such that $$E(\mathrm e^{-s\theta})=\exp\left(-\left(\sqrt{1+2s}-1\right)h\mu/\sigma^2\right).$$ 
For every fixed nonzero $(h,\mu,\sigma^2)$, $$\tau\stackrel{d}{=}\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^2}\Theta_\lambda,\qquad\lambda=\frac{h\mu}{\sigma^2},$$ where, for every positive $\lambda$, the distribution of the random variable $\Theta_\lambda$ is characterized by its Laplace transform $$E(\mathrm e^{-s\Theta_\lambda})=\exp\left(-\lambda\left(\sqrt{1+2s}-1\right)\right).$$
Thus, $$E(\Theta_\lambda)=\mathrm{var}(\Theta_\lambda)=\lambda.$$
Inverting the Laplace transform, one sees that $\Theta_\lambda$ has density $f_\lambda$, where, for every positive $t$, $$f_\lambda(t)=\frac{\lambda\exp(\lambda-t-\lambda^2/(4t))}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}}.$$
The regime $h\mu\gg\sigma^2$ corresponds to the limit $\lambda\to\infty$, then one has the convergence in probability $$\frac{\tau}{h\sigma}\to1.$$ Finally, the regime $h\mu\ll\sigma^2$ corresponds to the limit $\lambda\to0$, then one has the convergence in distribution $$\frac{\sigma^2}{h^2}\tau\to\vartheta,$$ where the distribution of $\vartheta$ is characterized by $$E(\mathrm e^{-s\vartheta})=\mathrm e^{-\sqrt{2s}}.$$
Inverting the Laplace transform, one sees that $\vartheta$ has density $g$, where, for every positive $t$, $$g(t)=\frac{\exp(-1/(2t))}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}},$$ hence $\vartheta=1/Z^2$ where $Z$ is standard normal, in particular $\vartheta$ is not integrable, and $$\tau\approx\frac{h^2}{\sigma^2Z^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer; it addresses every question I intend to ask. However when I try to apply it to the case I am working on, I encounter a numerical problem, and I cannot find where the problem is. In my case $\sigma^2=\mu=10^{-18}$ and $h=0.1$. We try to calculate $P(\tau\leq T_0)$, $T_0=3.6\times 10^{15}$. Then $\lambda=0.1$ and $\tau\leq T_0$ is equivalent to $\Theta_\lambda\leq 3.6\times 10^{-3}$. So $P(\tau\leq T_0)\leq \int_0^{3.6\times 10^{-3}}{\frac{\lambda\exp(\lambda-t-\lambda^2/(4t))}{2\sqrt{\pi t^3}}}=0.26$. (to be continued)

Comment: However we also have $P(\tau\leq T_0)=P(\max{\{S_1,...,S_{T_0}\}}\geq h) \geq P(S_{T_0}\geq h)$. By the central limit theorem, $S_{T_0}$ is approximately a normal distribution with mean $T_0\mu=3.6\times 10^{-3}$ and standard deviation $T_0\sigma=3.6\times 10^6$. With the huge deviation, $h$ is very close to its mean (The difference is a $3.6\times 10^7$-th of the standard deviation). Hence $P(S_{T_0}\geq h)\approx 1/2$. The beginning inequality will lead to $0.26\geq 0.5$. Is it because I made some wrong approximations?

Comment: Mistake: the standard deviation of $S_{T_0}$ is $\sigma\sqrt{T_0}$, not $\sigma T_0$, hence $P(S_{T_0}\gt h)$ is about $0.1\%$.

Comment: Oh my mistake. Now it makes sense to me.